# Converting from epochs using non-Gregorian calendars

Tags: r, date, calendar, lubridate, tidyverse

I'm working with a bunch of climate model ouput ([CMIP5 models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupled_model_intercomparison_project#Phase_5), specifically). These are netcdfs of timestamped temperature, wind, etc.

They all use a `days since YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00` convention in UTC. I've been converting to easier date (not date-time) objects using `lubridate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
input$date.utc =
  ymd_hms('0001-01-01 00:00:00', tz = 'UTC') +
  days(floor(input$time))
```

I've hit two problems. One is that each model has a different epoch. That's pretty easy to fix. The other, tougher, problem is that not all of the models use a Gregorian calendar. Some use a 365 day variation, where there are no leap years.

I don't see any way to specify a non-Gregorian calendar in the `lubridate` functions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find this functionality in `lubridate`, so I wrote a function to at least calculate the number of leap days between each element of a vector of dates and a given epoch:

```
# count_leap_days: returns an integer for the number of leap days between a
# supplied vector of dates and a fixed epoch
count_leap_days <- function(dates, epoch = ymd('1850-01-01'), proleptic = FALSE)
{
  require(lubridate)

  # check input
  if (!is(epoch, 'Date') | !is(dates, 'Date'))
  {
    stop('count_leap_days: both arguments must be Date objects.')
  }
  if (any(dates <= epoch))
  {
    stop('count_leap_days: dates should all be later than epoch.')
  }
  if (proleptic = FALSE & epoch < ymd('1582-10-15'))
  {
    message('count_leap_days: ',
      'no leap days before 1582-10-15 unless proleptic = TRUE.')
    epoch = ymd('1582-10-15')
  }

  # get the year range
  # exclude start (end) years if they begin after (start before) feb 29
  y.epoch = year(epoch) +
    ifelse(epoch >= ymd(paste0(year(epoch), '-03-01')), 1, 0)
  y.dates = year(dates) -
    ifelse(dates <= ymd(paste0(year(dates), '-02-28')), 1, 0)
  span = y.dates - y.epoch + 1

  # a year is a leap year if it's:
  #   - divisble by 4. but
  #   - NOT if it's also divisible by 100, unless
  #   - it's also divisible by 400.
  # all years div. by 4 are also div. by 100, and
  # all years div. by 100 are also div. by 400.
  # hence, total days = (div. by 4) - (div. by 100) + (div. by 400)
  div4 = span %/% 4 +
    ifelse(
      (y.epoch %% 4) %in% c(0, (4 - (span %% 4) - 1):(4 - 1)) &
      (y.dates %% 4) %in% 0:(span %% 4 - 1),
    1, 0)
  div100 = span %/% 100 +
    ifelse(
      (y.epoch %% 100) %in% c(0, (100 - (span %% 100) - 1):(100 - 1)) &
      (y.dates %% 100) %in% 0:(span %% 100 - 1),
    1, 0)
  div400 = span %/% 400 +
    ifelse(
      (y.epoch %% 400) %in% c(0, (400 - (span %% 400) - 1):(400 - 1)) &
      (y.dates %% 400) %in% 0:(span %% 400 - 1),
    1, 0)
  return(div4 - div100 + div400) 
}
```

With this, I can convert from a 365 day calendar to Gregorian by just adding the number of missing leap days:

```
input$date.utc = input$date.utc +
  count_leap_days(input$date.utc, epoch = epoch)
```